# kubernetes nginx ingress rewrite-target not work

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am following rewrite-target guide from https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/.
But it doesn't work as I expected

Here is my ingress.

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-rewrite-log: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "test.gamedrive.cc"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /player-gateway(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: player-gateway
                port:
                  number: 80
```

If make a request to **/player-gateway/health/startup**
it should rewritten to **/health/startup**.

But rewritten data from Nginx is **data: "/"** and got 404 error code. Here is the log from Nginx

> 2021/11/07 06:58:03 [notice] 312#312: *26100
> "(?i)/player-gateway(/|$)(.*)" matches
> "/player-gateway/health/startup", client: 113.53.150.16, server:
> test.gamedrive.cc, request: "GET /player-gateway/health/startup
> HTTP/1.1", host: "test.gamedrive.cc" 2021/11/07 06:58:03 [notice]
> 312#312: *26100 rewritten data: "/", args: "", client: 113.53.150.16,
> server: test.gamedrive.cc, request: "GET
> /player-gateway/health/startup HTTP/1.1", host: "test.gamedrive.cc"
> 113.53.150.16 - - [07/Nov/2021:06:58:03 +0000] "GET /player-gateway/health/startup HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-"
> "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4" 258 0.001 [default-player-gateway-80] []
> 10.244.0.109:80 139 0.000 404 e834c8338f2938ffc84db4e7e4053706

I try to debug by changed `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` to `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /health/startup`.

and the response code is 200 as expected

> 2021/11/07 07:04:32 [notice] 452#452: *29805
> "(?i)/player-gateway(/|$)(.*)" matches
> "/player-gateway/health/startup", client: 113.53.150.16, server:
> test.gamedrive.cc, request: "GET /player-gateway/health/startup
> HTTP/1.1", host: "test.gamedrive.cc" 2021/11/07 07:04:32 [notice]
> 452#452: *29805 rewritten data: "/health/startup", args: "", client:
> 113.53.150.16, server: test.gamedrive.cc, request: "GET /player-gateway/health/startup HTTP/1.1", host: "test.gamedrive.cc"
> 113.53.150.16 - - [07/Nov/2021:07:04:32 +0000] "GET /player-gateway/health/startup HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-"
> "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4" 258 0.002 [default-player-gateway-80] []
> 10.244.0.109:80 2 0.000 200 66967d6ab87d542f3269860107a4b7c4

Seem like /$2 or (/|$)(.*) is not working.

Please help me solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks really weird, like `$2` variable lost it's data somehow. What if you try named capture group: `path: /player-gateway(/|$)(?<gw>.*)`, `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$gw`?

Comment: @IvanShatsky I have tried and got the same result **rewritten data: "/",**

Comment: That's weird. Your yaml looks fine, it should work. Which version of Kubernetes are you using?

Comment: @p10l kubernetes version is 1.20.5.

Comment: which version of ingress-nginx controller?

Comment: @p10l not sure about the version. I followed this guide https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/ and install it via helm

Comment: can you check the `nginx.conf` file in the controller pod to see what  rewrite rule is being generated and if there is any other rewrites?

Comment: Have you come across a solution back then? I am facing the very same situation.

Comment: @rookie099 I moved to traefik